# Transform python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, transpose

Transform the following Python data frame.

| Country or Area | Year | Trade (USD) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Afghanistan | 2019 | 10.00 |
| India | 2019 | 30.00 |
| Pakisthan | 2019 | 13.00 |
| Iceland | 2019 | 40.00 |
| USA | 2019 | 51.00 |
| Afghanistan | 2020 | 12.00 |
| India | 2020 | 45.00 |
| Pakisthan | 2020 | 20.00 |
| Iceland | 2020 | 34.00 |
| USA | 2020 | 62.00 |

to the following format

| Year | Afghanistan | India | Pakisthan | Iceland | USA |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019 | 10 | 30 | 13 | 40 | 51 |
| 2020 | 12 | 45 | 20 | 34 | 62 |

Comment: See if [this answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73060100/19123103) your question. Don't forget `reset_index()`.

Comment: `df.pivot(index='Year', columns='Country or Area', values='Trade (USD)').reset_index().rename_axis(columns=None)` (or equivalent)